# Build a central routing database using the routing example in Omnet++

Tags: routes, omnet++, inet

I am trying to build a centralized routing database with Omnet++. I have an architecture like this one implemented in Omnet++:

```
module Node
{
    parameters:
        int address;
        string appType;
        @display("i=misc/node_vs,gold");
    gates:
        inout port[];     
    submodules:
        app: <appType> like InterfaceApp {
            parameters:
                address = address;
                @display("p=140,60");
        }
        routing: Routing {
            parameters:
                @display("p=140,130");
            gates:
                in[sizeof(port)];
                out[sizeof(port)];
        }
        queue[sizeof(port)]: InterfaceReseau {
            parameters:
                @display("p=80,200,row");
        }
    connections:
        routing.localOut --> app.in;
        routing.localIn <-- app.out;
        for i=0..sizeof(port)-1 {
            routing.out[i] --> queue[i].in;
            routing.in[i] <-- queue[i].out;
            queue[i].line <--> port[i];
        }
}
```

I would like at the beginning of the simulation, only one node builds all the re-routing paths an put them inside others nodes. I tried to create another module named "controller" containing submodules : "app" and "node". The "controller" module must  build all the re-routing paths and put them inside all node's modules. here is my .ned file:

```
module Controller
{
    parameters:
        int address;
        string appType;
        @display("i=misc/node_vs,gold");
    gates:
        inout port[];     
    submodules:
        app: <appType> like InterfaceApp {
            parameters:
                address = address;
                @display("p=140,60");
        }
        node: Node{
            parameters:
                @display("p=140,130");
            gates:
                in[sizeof(port)];
                out[sizeof(port)];
        }
}
```

it seems like this "Controller" module code is not correct to achieve my needs.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: Please also take the time to learn how the formatting tools work here. The toolbar icon looks like `{}` and there is plenty of documentation on how to use it. The more work you can put into making your question readable, the less work there is for volunteer editors to do.